# Speeding up for-loop over a list

Tags: performance, r

I have two lists with ca. 4000 elements where each each element have two columns. These are being fed into a function. Besides the function they are being fed into, is it possible to speed it up somehow? At this rate, it will take ca. 6-7 days to complete.

```
results=rep(0, length(as.numeric(unlist(coors))))
for(i in names(coors)){
  print(i)
  for( j in names(pols)){
    results[i]=point.in.polygon(coors[[i]][,1], coors[[i]][,2], pols[[j]][,1], pols[[j]][,2]) 
}}
```

EDIT: further description, I have the polygons for each ind in year 1 and the coordinates for year 2. I want to see how many of the locations from year 2 that falls within the polygon from year 1 for each individual.

EDIT 2:   the structure of `coors`

```
 str(coors)  
 List of 4052  
  $ 2225 :'data.frame': 48 obs. of  2 variables:  
   ..$ cor.x: num [1:48] 635184 635215 635394 635431 635430 ...  
   ..$ cor.y: num [1:48] 7151002 7151201 7151175 7151110 7151118 ...  
  $ 2226 :'data.frame': 56 obs. of  2 variables:  
   ..$ cor.x: num [1:56] 635945 635936 635944 635969 635947 ...  
   ..$ cor.y: num [1:56] 7152813 7152847 7152834 7152785 7152810 ...  
  $ 2227 :'data.frame': 56 obs. of  2 variables:  
   ..$ cor.x: num [1:56] 636244 636245 636317 636450 636386 ...  
   ..$ cor.y: num [1:56] 7151503 7151505 7151628 7151693 7151799 ...  
  $ 2228 :'data.frame': 56 obs. of  2 variables:  
   ..$ cor.x: num [1:56] 636451 636418 636408 636467 636495 ...  
  ..$ cor.y: num [1:56] 7152610 7152605 7152634 7152572 7152537 ...
```

There are always either 48 or 56 obs per element level. `Pols` have similar structure, but more variable lengths as the number of observations depends on the shape of the polygon.

Comment: I suggest you describe the task that you are trying to accomplish so that we can help you rethink the design.

Comment: Are these polygons mutually distinct? If so, you might save time by not checking further after a match is found. Any other constraints might help as well.

Comment: I have updated with some more description that I hope might help. @DWin they are not necessarily distinct and they don't need to be.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using `point.in.polygon` from the `sp` package. The function can take any number of points, so you should rewrite your algorithm as a single loop: for each polygon in `pols`, make a single call to `point.in.polygon` to check if **all** the points in `coords` are inside or not. This should save you a lot of time. Then you'll only have to do a little work reformatting the output. I can help with the code if you can please clarify what `coors` looks like.

**Edit**: Here is now an example of how you could code this into a single loop. It is possible you will have to work it a bit as you have not really shown us how you want to store your output.

First, some sample data:

```
coors <- replicate(5, {n <- sample(5:10, 1);
                       data.frame(x = runif(n), y = runif(n))},
                   simplify = FALSE)

pols <- replicate(3, {n <- sample(5:10, 1)
                      data.frame(x = runif(n), y = runif(n))},
                  simplify = FALSE)
```

Here, we concatenate all the points in `coors` together, but keep a vector of group indices which we will use later for splitting by group:

```
all.coors  <- do.call(rbind, coors)
num.points <- sapply(coors, nrow)
group.idx  <- rep(seq_along(coors), num.points)
```

Now the single loop:

```
results <- vector("list", length(pols)) 
for (j in seq_along(pols)) {
   print(j)
   results[[j]] <- split(point.in.polygon(all.coors[,1], all.coors[,2],
                                          pols[[j]][,1], pols[[j]][,2]),
                         group.idx)
}
```

I am confident this will significantly speed up your computations. However, if this is still too slow, I agree you'll have to consider parallelization. Good luck.

Comment: I have now added more description :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the time and effort! :) I have the coors also as a dataframe, so I was thinking about storing it as a new column there and then just use `ave()` to count number of 1's for each id.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a nested loop. Since the inner loop is executed 4000 times for each iteration of the outer loop, the total number of calls to point.in.polygon is 4000^2 so 16 million times.

The problem lies in how often the method is called and there is usually no direct way of speeding this up. **Loop execution is only the tiniest fraction of the runtime spend here**, the major amount of time will most likely be lost inside point.in.polygon. You can prove this by removing the function call to `point.in.polygon` and calling a dummy method instead.

Your best bet is finding a better algorithmic solution to your problem instead of trying to improve the brute force version you have here. As I understand it, you also overwrite the results[i] array for each inner call to point.in.polygon which basically means that only the last j-value's result will be saved anyway.

If you can not come up with a better algorithm, an alternative would be to execute the code in a multithreaded way. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395309/how-to-make-r-use-all-processors is a good starting point for that.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to look at multiprocessing. I thought I was adding the results of the function to the results-vector. The function results is simply a vector with 1s and 0s (are the coordinate inside or outside the polygon) as long as the vector for coordinates.